# How do I check if email submitted via Contact form 7 exists in my database (more than two times)?

Tags: wordpress

When customer submits email via contact form 7,
If more than two times of same email id exists in contact from db. Need to show the error message (Like you are already submitted more than 2 times)

For Example If test@gmail.com is already submitted two times via contact form 7 and contact form 7 db. Not allow to submit again

I have tried this code

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate', 'email_already_in_db', 10, 2 );

function email_already_in_db ( $result, $tags ) {
    // retrieve the posted email
    $form  = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $email = $form->get_posted_data('your-email');
    // if already in database, invalidate
    if( email_already_in_database( $email ) )
        $result->invalidate('your-email', 'Your email exists in our database');
    // return the filtered value
    return $result; }
```

But simple validation of email is also not working, When i use this code in function.php, after submit, loader keep on loading. Not submitting the data.

Answer (score 1):

Check with this plugin ,

https://github.com/mdsimpson/contact-form-7-to-database-extension

After that , please include this script if no inserted ,

https://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=904

```
/**
 * @param $formName string
 * @param $fieldName string
 * @param $fieldValue string
 * @return bool
 */
function is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $fieldValue) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBFormIterator.php');
    $exp = new CFDBFormIterator();
    $atts = array();
    $atts['show'] = $fieldName;
    $atts['filter'] = "$fieldName=$fieldValue";
    $atts['unbuffered'] = 'true';
    $exp->export($formName, $atts);
    $found = false;
    while ($row = $exp->nextRow()) {
        $found = true;
    }
    return $found;
}

/**
 * @param $result WPCF7_Validation
 * @param $tag array
 * @return WPCF7_Validation
 */
function my_validate_email($result, $tag) {
    $formName = 'email_form'; // Change to name of the form containing this field
    $fieldName = 'email_123'; // Change to your form's unique field name
    $errorMessage = 'Email has already been submitted'; // Change to your error message
    $name = $tag['name'];
    if ($name == $fieldName) {
        if (is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name])) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

// use the next line if your field is a **required email** field on your form
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
// use the next line if your field is an **email** field not required on your form
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);

// use the next line if your field is a **required text** field
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
// use the next line if your field is a **text** field field not required on your form 
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution for you that does not require any server interaction. Instead of querying the database each time a user sends an email why not store sent email details locally and then compare them on the client side? 
Using JavaScript you can add the information from each sent email to an array kept inside a variable in the `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`. Then if that user tries to send another email the content of all previous sent emails will be checked to make sure it's not a duplicate.